# como registrar datos de horómero en base de datos?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Quisiera que me orienten como podría registrar los datos de un **horómetro** en base de datos. El **horómetro** permite hacer el conteo de horas de uso de una maquinaria, utiliza un decimal que va del 0 al 5, pasado el 5 se reinicia el decimal y se incrementa una hora. Mi dilema es cual es la mejor forma de guardar esta información.

Uso `MYSQL` e intenté guardar en un campo tipo `DECIMAL` con 1 dígito, pero este **contea** del 0 al 9, así que no me sirve para este caso.

Alguien me orienta cual es la mejor forma please.

Comment: ¿Y cual es el problema de que DECIMAl vaya de 0 a 9? Simplemente usas de 0 a 5 y ya esta.

Comment: el problema es que luego hare operaciones con decimales y si sumo 1.4 + 1.5 .. usando decimal me dara 2.9, y el horometro no tiene el digito 9, solo del 0 al 5.... me dejo entender???

Comment: Para eso puedes prepararte funciones que se encarguen de hacer bien el redondeo. Les pasas los 2 parametros y ellas te devuelven la suma correcta. Tambien puedes hacerlo en código fuente y no en bbdd.

Comment: Muy util la sugerencia, en vano quise hacerlo directo a la BD, en codigo fuente ya lo veo facil... gracias por la ayuda @JDev